# Hidden label value in google form's grid

Tags: google-docs, google-forms

I'm using Google Forms to have people answer a questionnaire.
Basically, I don't want to bias the answers and since I have to use the famous NASA TLX (http://humansystems.arc.nasa.gov/groups/tlx/downloads/TLXScale.pdf)
I would love to be able to have the same kind of layout, i.e 20 different possible answers, each one with a value but only the "Very High" or "Very Low" visible to the user.

Is that possible?

If it is I would really like to know how to do it because I just can't find a way.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have three options:

1. It sounds like what you are looking for is the "Scale" question type. This, however, would only allow for 0 to 10.
2. To get 20 you would have to pick a multiple choice question and add 20 options. The first being "very low", the last "very high" and " " [spaces] in between. This would give you a vertical version of the NASA Task Load Index, however.
3. To get a horizontal version use a question type of "Grid" and use spaces and very low/high.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indeed i've seen the limitation of the scale option. The multiple choice doesn't really look cool to me. I'm currently using the grid, but I don't get any value when using the grid if the user doesn't pick either Very low or Very High. Thanks for the suggestions though, upvote deserved :)

Comment: Oh! I see now. How about using different numbers of spaces?

Comment: It would seem that spaces are automatically removed if no other input is provided :(

Comment: Dang. Sorry then :( I even looked at changing the font color, but no luck there. You can't even paste white text

Comment: Yes I've tried that too. Thanks anyway for the help. Well in that case there might be a tool that you would recommend to do so. Problem is it has to be here and I have to be able to download the results as a csv

Comment: You are already way over my head. I tried looking for an app on google. You may be able to write some script, but I would be no help there either :)